# Access SQL Azure Storage in Linux

Tags: linux, azure-sql-database

I just want to ask if it is possible to connect or access SQL Azure Storage in Linux?
If yes could i have some tutorial. 
Thank You very much.
I need this ASAP.
More power to you! Thanks! :D

Comment: You can use the REST API http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd179355.aspx and there is no shortage of samples for calling REST APIs in many languages that are implemented in Linux

Comment: Thanks for you answer could you me other tutorials?

Comment: I think you'll need to do some research first